# How can I share or add a place or Check-in using Facebook SDK 4.0?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been exploring the Facebook documentations but still yet to find on how to Check-in or share place. Most answers were already deprecated and I need to implement using the updated Facebook SDK. Did I miss something in the Documentations? Or do I have to use third party applications??? Besides the primary way of Sharing using the SDK, I also know how to use ACTION_SEND on sharing media content on facebook, is it possible to insert a place parameter there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using facebook share button it'll be like this

```
ShareContent sharecontent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setPlaceId("141887372509674")
            .build();

    btnfacebookshare.setShareContent(sharecontent);
```

Put a placeID on ShareContents

There are also ShareContent subclasses you may use with setPlaceId() like SharePhotoContent, ShareVideoContent, and ShareOpenGraphContent.

It is not clearly stated on the documentations (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareLinkContent/) but with experimentations I came up with it

Comment: I'll try I need to revise the structure. Coz I'm currently using ACTION_SEND

Comment: Where the heck this `placeId` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

The placeId needs to be requested using `GraphRequest` which can be done using:

```
    String facebookUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/mybusiness";
    final String PAGE_ID_FROM_URL = facebookUrl.substring(facebookUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, facebookUrl.length());//now PAGE_ID_FROM_URL = mybusiness 
  //request for page id      
  new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/"+ PAGE_ID_FROM_URL , null, HttpMethod.GET,
          new GraphRequest.Callback() {
             public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                        if (obj.has("id")) {
                            try {
                               String pageID = obj.getString("id");
                               ShareDialog share = new ShareDialog(MyActivity.this);
                               ShareContent shareContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setPlaceId(pageID).setPageId(pageID).build();
                               share.show(shareContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);

                         } catch (JSONException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }                   
    }
     }).executeAsync();
```